# Automatic updates of iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, deployment

Is it possible to automatically force an update of all installations of an iPhone app without requiring interaction from the users?

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551918/iphone-managing-version-updates-of-a-native-app) it is impossible to do so for apps deployed on Apple's public app store, but [another more recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291159/detecting-iphone-app-version-update) describes a way to at least inform users of updates, but still forces them to take action manually. With the Enterprise Program becoming available to most companies now (the requirement of 500+ employees has been dropped) can we hope to achieve it with the Enterprise Program?

The reason I'm asking is that automated push-updates of applications are a common demand and indispensable requirement by many businesses that use mobile devices. Blackberries have always won over iPhones in the past, because they had this feature while iPhones did not. Has the situation changed now?

**Update:** Apparently, there is another problem. Apple has a [limit on the size of app downloads](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10456067-233.html) of 20MB over GSM which to my understanding also applies to deployment within the Enterprise Program. Unless all users consistently have access to a WiFi connection, this is another limitation that needs to be taken into consideration.

**Update 2:** I have submitted a feature request to Apple. Maybe it helps to expedite the improvements.

Comment: @Matthew: For mobile users who do not work in-house (a common situation), WiFi often is not an option. Some businesses also ban WiFi in-house, although this strongly depends on who one is talking to. In general, we can rely on iPhones being accessible via the cell phone network, but we can not rely on dozens or even hundreds of users having access to a working WLAN connection. So a size limit may be a real issue that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: I follow why it's still a likely issue, I just wanted to make sure you understood the policy. I also expect you'll see changes in some of the carrier-driven policies in the coming month or so. Competition does crazy things. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can force an update, though you can:

- Remotely disable an existing app, if urgent, and
- Design your app such that when it is outdated it alerts the user and provides a one-tap link to download a new version (technically two taps, one to load the web page with the app and one to install the new version).

It's not the ideal system you note would be so helpful, but it's an improvement over the earlier system where users had to sync with iTunes at a desktop/laptop in order to perform the upgrade.